# How to write a 2 degree expression as sum of squares of two linear expressions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to write $2x^2+y^2+2xy+2x-3y+8$ in the form $\frac {1}{m}((ax+by+c)^2+(dx+ey+f)^2+n)$ so as to find the minimum value of the expression ? I'm looking for a direct method which does not involve guess work.

Comment: There are easier ways to find the minimum, but... How familiar are you with linear algebra and diagonalization?

Comment: @Arthur I know about matrices and determinants (basics) . Not much idea about diagonalization.

Comment: i have found this here $$ \left( y+x-3/2 \right) ^{2}+2\, \left( x+1/2 \right) ^{2}+15/2-1/4\,
 \left( 2\,x-3 \right) ^{2}
 
$$

Comment: Why will writing it in that form let you easily find the minimum value of the expression? To ensure that you can minimize using that form, wouldn't you also need to know that $ae - bd \ne 0$?

Comment: @JohnHughes I want to write it in the shown form first. Whether I will get the minima or not, that's secondary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it more straightforward to complete the square in $x$ first so you have $$2[x^2+x(y+1)]+y^2-3y+8$$
$$=2[(x+\frac 12(y+1))^2-\frac 14(y+1)^2]+y^2-3y+8$$

Now complete the square in the remaining $y$ terms so you end up with 
$$2[(x+\frac 12(y+1)]^2+\frac 12(y-4)^2-\frac 12$$

From this we can deduce that the minimum is $-\frac 12$ when $y=4\implies x=-\frac 52$

Comment: This is a "direct method that does not involve guesswork", but it also won't always produce the result you expect. Consider, for instance, $x^2 + 2xy + y^2 + 2x + 1$, which leads to $(x + (y+1))^2 + ...$; when you work out the remaining terms, you'll see what goes wrong. That's why I took the time to write out my rather extended answer.

Answer (score 2):

Write the equation in matrix form:
$$
Q = \begin{bmatrix}
x & y & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & -\frac{3}{2} \\
1 & -\frac{3}{2} & 8
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Then, because the matrix is symmetric, you can diagonalize it in a purely mechanical process --- although to do so, you'll need to solve a cubic, which Cardano's formula can do for you, again mechanically. Then you have
$$
Q = \begin{bmatrix}
x & y & 1\end{bmatrix}
R^t D R
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
where $R$ is an orthogonal matrix, and $D$ is diagonal. Writing

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\ y'\\ z' \end{bmatrix} =
 R
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
gives you three linear expressions in $x, y$ and $1$. And then you have
$$
Q = \begin{bmatrix}
x' & y' & z'\end{bmatrix}
 D 
\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\y'\\z'
\end{bmatrix},
$$
which expresses your original thing as a sum of three squares, each being the square of a linear expression in $x$ and $y$.

Now using Cardano's formula is a pain, and diagonalizing a matrix involves solving at least two systems  of three simultaneous equations, and the end result is a sum of *three* quadratic expressions rather than two, but it seems to me that this tells you how to go about doing what you've proposed, mostly. It also serves as advice *not to try to do this in this way.*

Answer (score 2):

Since you say that writing it as a sum of two quadratics is your real goal, things are a good deal easier. Write

$$
Q = Ax^2 + 2B xy + C y^2 + 2Dx + 2Ey + F
$$

(the factors of $2$ here makes the algebra nicer later on). 
Then write down two associated equations:
$$
\begin{align}
Ax + By + D &= 0\\
Bx + Cy + E &= 0
\end{align},
$$
and solve to get a point $(s, t)$. (This can fail if $AC - B^2 = 0$, of course.)

Substitute $x = u+s, y = v + t$ into your original equation, and you'll end up with something of the form
$$
Q = au^2 + 2b xuv + cv^2 + f
$$
The quadratic portion of that can be written as
$$
Q - f = \begin{bmatrix}
u & v
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\b & c
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u\\v
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Once again, diagonalization is your friend, but for $2 \times 2$ matrices, it's comparatively easy:

Let $r$ be either root of the quadratic
$$
(a - x)(c-x) - b^2 = 0,
$$
which you can find using the quadratic formula. If your expression HAS a minimum (rather than a max or a saddle), then  both roots will be nonnegative).

Now let
$$
w = \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2 + (r-a)^2}}\begin{bmatrix} b \\ r-a \end{bmatrix}\\
z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2 + (r-a)^2}}\begin{bmatrix} a-r \\ b \end{bmatrix} 
$$
and let $R$ be the matrix whose columns are $w$ and $z$. Let $r'$ denote the other root of the quadratic above. Then we have
$$
Q - f = \begin{bmatrix}
u & v
\end{bmatrix}
R^t \begin{bmatrix}
r & 0 \\0 & r'
\end{bmatrix}
R\begin{bmatrix}
u\\v
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Writing  $p = R\begin{bmatrix}
u\\v
\end{bmatrix}$, which is a linear expression in $x$ and $y$ when you expand it all out, we now have
$$
Q  = f + p^t \begin{bmatrix}
r & 0 \\0 & r'
\end{bmatrix}
p = f + r p_1^2 + r' p_2^2
$$
where $p_1$ and $p_2$ denote the first and second entries of the matrix $p$. And that's the form you asked for, via a strictly mechanical process.

Why does this process work? Well, the equations leading to $(s,t)$ came from calculus. Writing the expression in terms of $u,v$ came from linear algebra. Diagonalization was possible by Sylvester's Law of Inertia. In short: it was possible by stuff you'll be learning in a little while, developed by people who had to solve problems like the one you asked, and got frustrated by not having a mecahnical way to do so. ;)

N.B.: My note about "this can fail if..." is not to be ignored. Consider the case $Q = x^2 + 2xy + y^2 + 4x + 2y$. The pair of $st$-equations has no solution, but that's because $Q = (x+y)^2 + 4x +2y$, which cannot be written in the form you described. So there's no general mechanical process for solving the problem you posed, because the problem doesn't always have a solution.

Also: The solution I gave may in some cases lead to cases where $r$ and $r'$ are negative; these negative values must be taken out into your "$m$" factor in the front to get the form you desired.